# Finding the eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> The matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}5&0&0\\-7&-2&0\\12&2&0\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $-2,0, $ and $5$. Find its associated eigenvectors for each eigenvalue

So I started with $\lambda_1 = -2$ to get $\begin{bmatrix}5-(-2)&0&0\\-7&-2-(-2)&0\\12&(2--2)&0\end{bmatrix}$ ~ $\begin{bmatrix} 7&0&0\\-7&0&0\\12&4&0\end{bmatrix}$

So I know I have

$7x = 0$ which doesn't tell me anything

so I see that $12x +4y = 0 \implies 12x = -4y \implies x = 1, y = -3$ so I thought that a eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = -2$ would be $(1,-3,0)$ but for some reason I am incorrect. Am i in error in my method? Is there a difference between a ***corresponding*** eigenvector and a ***associated*** eigenvector? I was under the impression they were the same thing

**UPDATE** (Had subtracted lambda from the wrong row/column)

Now I get: $\begin{bmatrix} 7&0&0\\-7&0&0\\12&2&-2\end{bmatrix}$

so $7x = 0 \implies x = 0$ so then I have $2y = 2z \implies y = 1, z = 1$  so that the eigenvector associated with $-2$ is $(1,1,0)$ ? But that is incorrect also, where am I in error?

Comment: Why did you subtract $-2$ from the $(3,2)$ entry rather than the $(3,3)$ entry?

Comment: @carmichael561 OP has been updated

Comment: The last row should be $12,2,2$, right?

Comment: Augh, wow. @carmichael561

Comment: @carmichael561 Still I am getting the incorrect answer. Yes, you are right though. Now I am getting $(0,1,-1)$ which is also incorrect

Comment: I think $(0,1,-1)$ should work. If you apply $A$ to this vector you get $(0,-2,2)$, right?

Comment: Ah, yes it did work. Thank you @carmichael561

Comment: @carmichael561 Now I'm getting $(0,0,0)$ for $\lambda = 0$ and $(1,-1,2)$ for $\lambda = 5$ but one is incorrect

Comment: $(1,-1,2)$ is fine, but for the other one you want a non-zero vector. How about $(0,0,1)$?

Comment: Why does $(1,-6,0)$ not work? Is that not a non-zero vector? Since we can do $\begin{bmatrix}5&0&0\\-7&-2&0\\12&2&0\end{bmatrix}$ ~ $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\5&0&0\\12&2&0\end{bmatrix} \implies 12x = -2y \implies x = 1, y = -6, z = 0$?

Comment: The second row tells you $x$ must be zero.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Wow

Comment: You are correct, I see that now @carmichael561 thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

So, if $A = \begin{bmatrix}5&0&0\\-7&-2&0\\12&2&0\end{bmatrix}$ we want to find its associated eigenvectors for each eigenvalue.

Let's start with $\lambda_1 = -2$. We find that the matrix ($A-\lambda_1Id$) where $Id = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is

$A_1 = \begin{bmatrix}7&0&0\\-7&0&0\\12&2&2\end{bmatrix}$ (pay attention, it's 2 on $a_{33}$ not -2 because you are subtracting -2).

We now find that it must be $x=0$, $y=-z$. So the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1$ is $(0,1,-1)$.

We do the same with the other eigenvalues, $\lambda_2=0$ and $\lambda_3=5$.

$A_2 = \begin{bmatrix}5&0&0\\-7&-2&0\\12&2&0\end{bmatrix}$

From which we see that $x=0, y=0, z=\alpha$ with $\alpha\in K$ where $K$ is the field you are considering. So the eigenvector corrisponding to $\lambda_2$ is $(0,0,\alpha)$.

$A_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\-7&-7&0\\12&2&-5\end{bmatrix}$

From which we see $x=-y, z=2x$ so the eigenvector related to $\lambda_3$ is $(1,-1,2)$.